# React-Native ScrollView scrolling both vertically and horizontally

Tags: react-native, scroll, react-native-scrollview

for my app, I need `ScrollView` component to be scrolled both vertically and horizontally. I searched quite a lot but, could not come out to solution. Tried `directionLockEnabled`, did not work. `contentContainerStyle` is not way, because my row and columns numbers are dynamic, it may expand in both direction. I believe there should be some way to make `ScrollView` scrolled in both directions.

Here is my `ScrollView` picture inside DataGrid

[image]

Here is my `ScrollView` code inside the dataGrid(`react-native-easy-grid`)

```
 <Grid style={{ width: width - 20, height: height / 2 }}>
<ScrollView
    horizontal={true}
    style={{
        height: height / 2,
        width: width - 20,
        marginLeft: 20,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#D3D3D3"
    }}
>
    <Col style={{ width: 200 }}>
        <Row
            style={{
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: "#D3D3D3",
                height: 80,
                alignItems: "center"
            }}
        >
            <Text>{this.state.Wholesaler}</Text>
        </Row>
        {this.state.dataGrid.map((person, i) => {
            return (
                <Row
                    key={i}
                    style={{
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        borderColor: "#D3D3D3",
                        height: 50,
                        alignItems: "center"
                    }}
                >
                    <Text>{person.name}</Text>
                </Row>
            );
        })}
    </Col>
    <Col style={{ width: 200 }}>
        <Row
            style={{
                height: 40,
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: "#D3D3D3"
            }}
        >
            <Text>Operator</Text>
        </Row>
        <Row style={{ height: 40 }}>
            <Col
                style={{
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: "#D3D3D3",
                    alignItems: "center"
                }}
            >
                <Text>Target</Text>
            </Col>
            <Col
                style={{
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: "#D3D3D3",
                    alignItems: "center"
                }}
            >
                <Text>Actual</Text>
            </Col>
            <Col
                style={{
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: "#D3D3D3",
                    alignItems: "center"
                }}
            >
                <Text>%</Text>
            </Col>
        </Row>
        {this.state.dataGrid.map((person, i) => {
            return (
                <Row key={i} style={{ height: 50 }}>
                    <Col
                        style={{
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderColor: "#D3D3D3",
                            alignItems: "center"
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text>{person.OperatorTarget}</Text>
                    </Col>
                    <Col
                        style={{
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderColor: "#D3D3D3",
                            alignItems: "center"
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text>{person.OperatorActual}</Text>
                    </Col>
                    <Col
                        style={{
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderColor: "#D3D3D3",
                            alignItems: "center"
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text>{person.OperatorPercent}</Text>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            );
        })}
    </Col>
    <Col style={{ width: 200 }}>
        <Row
            style={{
                height: 40,
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: "#D3D3D3"
            }}
        >
            <Text>Lead</Text>
        </Row>
        <Row style={{ height: 40 }}>
            <Col
                style={{
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: "#D3D3D3",
                    alignItems: "center"
                }}
            >
                <Text>Target</Text>
            </Col>
            <Col
                style={{
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: "#D3D3D3",
                    alignItems: "center"
                }}
            >
                <Text>Actual</Text>
            </Col>
            <Col
                style={{
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: "#D3D3D3",
                    alignItems: "center"
                }}
            >
                <Text>%</Text>
            </Col>
        </Row>
        {this.state.dataGrid.map((person, i) => {
            return (
                <Row key={i} style={{ height: 50 }}>
                    <Col
                        style={{
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderColor: "#D3D3D3",
                            alignItems: "center"
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text>{person.LeadTarget}</Text>
                    </Col>
                    <Col
                        style={{
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderColor: "#D3D3D3",
                            alignItems: "center"
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text>{person.LeadActual}</Text>
                    </Col>
                    <Col
                        style={{
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderColor: "#D3D3D3",
                            alignItems: "center"
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text>{person.LeadPercent}</Text>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            );
        })}
    </Col>
</ScrollView>
</Grid>;
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this thing from one of the issues on GitHub. You can use two scrollviews. One for horizontal and other for vertical.

```
<ScrollView>
    <ScrollView horizontal>
          .....
    </ScrollView>
<ScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried nested ScrollView, as well. But, it did not work for me.

Comment: This did sorta work (not very smooth) but I'm not a fan. I am using RN 0.68.2 wonder if there is a bug with ScrollViews in that version.

Answer (score 1):

The horizontal ScrollView scrolls the components and views from left to right. It will be implemented by setting the props horizontal to true (horizontal={true})

```js
<ScrollView  horizontal={true}> 
      ....your code 
  </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a `<ScrollView>` as many times as you want and you can specify if you want it horizontal or vertical, right before the `<View>` or the `<WebView>`

Example:

```
<ScrollView>
    <ScrollView horizontal>
        <View>
            <WebView (your code) />
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```